# How to improve email robustness? [mailgun, laravel]

Tags: laravel, mailgun, laravel-mail

I planned to improve email robustness using below way. I am using `laravel` and `mailgun`. If any **bounces email** is in the `mailgun` then i want to send that to someone related to the email(not to that previous receiver and it related with previous sender or someone) so that i plan to use **Task scheduler** and schedule every hour this process. After that email send successfully i want to remove that email from `mailgun`.

I actually want to know how to implement get **bounces email** from `mailgun` and if send successfully using **Task scheduler** i want to remove that email from `mailgun`. if any sample's to achieve this? or any different ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when a bounce happens, providers such as Mailgun will retry a few times depending on the bounce status/type. After failing to send to that email address, Mailgun will put that address into your Bounces list to avoid sending to that address in the future. There's really no point in trying to send emails to an address which doesn't exist, inbox is full, domain expired, etc. So perhaps you should review your bounce list before you consider doing this. Mailgun's dashboard provides the description and date it happened. If you wish to send to a particular address again, you can remove the address from the bounce list. More about bounces [here](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/email-bounces-what-to-do-about-them/).

You can use [mailgun-php](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php) or simply use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) to call their [API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-bounces.html#bounces) to retrieve your bounces. I'm not sure what you meant my removing email, but hope this helps.

**Edit:**

You can use their API to get all your [bounces](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-suppressions.html#view-all-bounces), and also the [message content](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages) (retention depends on your plan or settings) if you need the original content. You could also use their [webhooks](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-webhooks.html#webhooks) to get the failed emails, so you don't really need to schedule/cron.

**Edit 2:**

The bounce list only stores email addresses of previously bounced emails. Also, I just realized that, if you're checking hourly for bounced messages, looks like the suppression/bounce API won't be of much help since you can't know if a message has failed for an address already on the list. This is the only data from bounce list:

```
      {
        "address": "alice@example.com",
        "code": "550",
        "error": "No such mailbox",
        "created_at": "Fri, 21 Oct 2011 11:02:55 GMT"
      },
```

So looks like you've to use the [events API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#event-types) or [webhooks](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-webhooks.html#webhooks) to get the failed messages.
I've used [mailgun-php](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php) sometime ago, and I found that the it wasn't easy working with Events on that library due to protected properties of the class. So if you have trouble, maybe just use Guzzle or use webhook approach instead.

Comment: Hey @sykez Thanks for your answer. Now i updated my question can you please look at again. Now i guess it will give full idea what i want to try. Can you please update your answer regarding this(if anything you want change)

Comment: @Dev I see. If it's not to the original recipient, should be alright. I've updated my answer with a bit more options. However I still don't quite understand what you meant by removing email from Mailgun. If you're talking about the message content, they only store them based on your retention limit based on your plan/settings, so I don't think you really need to worry about that.

Comment: Actually i plan to check email bounces every one hour using Task scheduler and it send to as i mentioned way. If that particular bounce email related thing send successful as mentioned way. Then i think that related email content not needed in the bounces list. so that i want to remove that from list. Are you thing is it ok?

Comment: currently i have mailgun account without card registered so how can use that for my local development purpose. For example my current local application url look like `https://app.laraapp.test/`. How to do above things with this any idea? or any preferred resources? @sykez Thanks.

Comment: @Dev The bounce list is only a list of addresses. I think you should still keep the address in the bounce list to avoid Mailgun to keep sending, unless the address is working fine now. You should review your bounce list periodically anyway. As for the email content, you can just keep it and let Mailgun do their retention. I've updated my answer with some more info btw.

Comment: @Dev You'll need an actual verified domain in your account to use without their limitations. I think you'll need to add a card as well to get past some other limitations too. There's a 3 month trial as well if you wish to try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218014/discussion-between-sykez-and-dev).